# bash - Diff a command with a file (specific)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

so its pretty hard to describe for me what I want to do, but I'll try it:
(Because of some private information I changed the names)

I want to "diff" a command output with a text file created from me. 
The command output looks like:

```
  'Blabla1' '12.34.56.78' (24 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING'
  'Blabla3' '12.34.56.89' (89 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING'
```

And the txtfile:

```
Blabla1
Blabla2
```

If it finds Blabla1 anywhere in the command output its fine. But you see, he will not find Blabla2 **anywhere** in the command output and this difference I want as an output.

I hope you understand what I mean and you could possible help me.

Greetings,
Can

**UPDATE::::**

@hek2mgl

So my command is:

> ./factory.sh listapplications | grep -i running

This command shows this:

```
'ftp' '1' (7 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING' - 'XSD Da
'abc' '5.1.0' (14 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING' - '2017-10-13: Fix fuer Bug 2150'
'name' '1.0.2' (5 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING'
```

And I want to compare that output with my textfile:

```
ftp
abc
name
missing
alsomissing
```

So if I compare this 2 now it should check if he finds the words from my textfile ANYWHERE in the command output. If it does find it anywhere -> not output.

And as you see he'll not find "missing" and "alsomissing". I want this two as an output at the end.

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for, and what command(s) have you tried so far? You will get better answers if your question contains an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: @ghoti I just tried diff, but diff wants that the two outputs are the same and I cant search for just one word in the other output...

Comment: I can't replicate your results based on what you've provided.

Comment: @ghoti as far as I understand the OP wants `Blabla2` as the output.

Comment: Thats right. I want Blabla2 as the output

Answer (score 1):

What you might be interested in is `grep` in combination with 'process substitution'.  If your file with patterns is `file.txt` and your command to execute is `cmd` then you can use

```
grep -o -F -f file.txt <(cmd) | grep -v -F -f - file.txt
```

This will output the patterns is `file.txt` which are not matched in the output of `cmd`.

In case of the `Blabla` example, the above line will output

```
Blabla2
```

How it works is the following. The first part will search for all patterns listed in `file.txt` in the output of `cmd` and will only output the matched parts. This means that

```
% grep -o -F -f file.txt <(cmd)
Blabla1
```

This output is now piped to another command that will try to find all lines in `file.txt` which do not match any of the patterns comming from the pipe (`-f -`)

```
% grep -o -F -f file.txt <(cmd) | grep -v -F -f - file.txt
Blabla2
```

Comment: That was my first intention too but that does not produce the output the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer as more information is now available to what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you, this one works too, now I need to test hek2mgl answer :D

Comment: @CanLotoz Na, you don't need to. Pick of these remaining answers. They are better.

Comment: @CanLotoz, you're welcome. As you clearly see, multiple solutions are available to achieve the same goal. `grep`, `sed` and `awk` are very powerfull. `awk` can do all the othe tools can. I suggest to look at http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

So ... this seems to do it, using bash process substitution:

```
$ cat file1
  'Blabla1' '12.34.56.78' (24 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING'
  'Blabla3' '12.34.56.89' (89 objects + dependencies), STATUS: 'RUNNING'
$ cat file2
Blabla1
Blabla2
$ grep -vFf <(awk '{gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"",$1);print $1}' file1) file2
Blabla2
```

The `awk` script takes the first field, strips non-alphanumeric characters from it (i.e. the single quotes) and outputs just that first field. The `grep` option `-f` uses the "virtual" file created by the aforementioned process substitution as a list of fixed strings to search for within the input file (file2), and the `-v` reverses the search, showing you only what was not found.

If the regex in the `gsub()` is too greedy, you might replace it with something like `$1=substr($1,2,length($1)-2)`.

You could alternately do this in (POSIX) `awk` alone, without relying on bash process substitution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[substr($1,2,length($1)-2)];next} $1 in a{next} 1' file1 file2
Blabla2
```

This reads the stripped first field of `file1` into the keys of an array, then for each line of `file2` checks for the existence of that key in the array, skipping lines that match and printing any left over.  (The `1` at the end of the script is short-hand for "print this line".)

Comment: My pleasure. Kudos to hek2mgl for patiently walking through the discovery process with you.

Comment: :) I've undeleted it. But ghoti's awk solution is efficient as my but simpler because he inverted the logic somehow so he doesn't need the `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` only:

```
awk '
# Store patterns of text.file in an array (p)atterns.
# Initialize their count of occurrence with 0
NR==FNR{
    p[$0]=0
    next
}

# Replace the quotes around BlaBla... in cmd output.
# Increase the count of occurrence of the pattern
{
    gsub("'\''", "")
    p[$1]++
}

# At the end of the input print those patterns which
# did not appear in cmd output, meaning their count of
# occurrence is zero.
END{
    for(i in p){
        if(p[i]==0){
            print i
        }
    }
}' text.file cmd.txt
```

PS: Alternatively you use *process substitution* instead of storing the command output in a file. Replace `cmd.txt` by `<(cmd)` then.

Comment: I added explanations already. Hard to explain the full `awk` language in one post. :)

Comment: @CanLotoz Did you try the command? If it does not work, then please post real world examples of the command output and the text file.

Comment: Im working on it. At the moment it doesnt work, but I think I first need to understand your post better. Give me 5 more minutes.

Comment: Okey lets do it with real world examples. Im going to make a new comment so you can better read it

Comment: Ok. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @CanLotoz I fixed a little typo in the awk command. But it is working an prints `missing` and `alsomissing` with your real world data

Comment: Btw, you can compress the `awk` command to: `awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0]=0;next}{gsub("'\''", "");p[$1]++}END{for(i in p){if(p[i]==0){print i}}}'` if you want.

Comment: The nice thing here is that with a small adjustment, you can get rid of the `grep -i running` and throw everything into the single `awk` command.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you really much for your help. Really. I appreciate this very much. I tested yours and it works now too. I just need to understand it now and learn from it -> But with this google helps me. Thank you.

Comment: @CanLotoz You are welcome. :) I recommend to learn `awk` from scratch. It's a very powerful tool for a broad range of use cases. Probably you order an O'Reilly or so...

Comment: @hek2mgl my compliments for Walking CanLotoz trough the process.